# How to convert file to machine embroidery format?

Tags: file-conversion, embroidery, dst

How can I easily convert my bitmap logo into a DST file for use in embroidery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your assumption that there is no software to automatically perform this conversion is pretty accurate. There are online conversion tools that can do the conversion for you, but in my (admittedly limited) experience, they don't produce a file that is fit for purpose.

On the rare occasion that I have needed to convert a file for embroidery machines, after much hunting for a way to do it myself, I found that the best option was to get a professional specialist to do it for me; for the following reasons:

- There are subtleties in the conversion process involving things such as the direction and ideal length of the stitches that require experience and knowledge that most of us (and the automated software) don't have. It's a bit of an art.
- The software required to do it properly is pretty expensive (or was last time I looked).
- You kind of need to have the hardware (embroidery machine) in order to check your work by producing a sample using the correct material and thread.
- The charge for somebody else to do the conversion is relatively cost effective and can save you a ton of time.
- You may well be able to find a supplier of the finished product who will do the conversion for you for a reasonable additional fee. This can be a good solution because it moves the responsibility for the conversion process closer to the production and gives them the opportunity to allow for the particular needs of their processes and machinery.

In short; If this is something that you are going to be doing every day then invest in the proper machinery and software, if not, outsource it.